# Javascript OR in an IF statement

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make an if statement in javascript that will do something if the variable does not equal one of a few different things. I have been trying many different variations of the OR operator, but I cant get it to work.

```
 if(var != "One" || "Two" || "Three"){
    // Do Something
    }
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

**Update:**

I have tried this before:

```
 if(var != "One" || var != "Two" || var != "Three"){
    // Do Something
    }
```

For some reason it does not work. My variable is pulling information from the DOM i dont know if that would effect this.

**Actual Code**

```
// Gets Value of the Field (Drop Down box)
var itemtype = document.forms[0].elements['itemtype' + i];

    if(itemtype.value != "Silverware" || itemtype.value != "Gold Coins" || itemtype.value != "Silver Coins"){   
// Do Something
        }
```

Comment: as a side note: var is a keyword, not a variable name

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your expression is always true, you need:

```
if(!(myVar == "One" || myVar == "Two" || myVar == "Three")) { 
  // myVar is not One, Two or Three
}
```

Or:

```
if ((myVar != "One") && (myVar != "Two") && (myVar != "Three")) {
  // myVar is not One, Two or Three
}
```

And, for shortness:

```
if (!/One|Two|Three/.test(myVar)) {
  // myVar is not One, Two or Three
}
// Or:
if (!myVar.match("One|Two|Three")) {
  // ...
}
```

More info:

- [De Morgan's Laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws)

**Edit:** If you go for the last approaches, since the code you posted *seems* to be part of a loop, I would recommend you to create the regular expression outside the loop, and use the [`RegExp.prototype.test`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/RegExp/Test) method rather than [`String.prototype.match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference:Objects:String:match), also you might want to care about *word boundaries*, i.e. "noOne" will match "One" without them...

Comment: Thank you, finally a sensible answer. I will try it now.

Comment: I would use the regexp `!myVar.match(/One|Two|Three/)` instead of passing in the string - but +1 for covering all the bases

Comment: @Chris... he has 56K for a reason :)   @CMS +1, great answer as always

Comment: @gnarf, Agree, and the RegExp should be created outside the loop (the code fragment appears to be part of a loop (`...['itemtype' + i];...`))

Comment: Wait, doesn't the OP want to do something *only* if the value is not "One" or "Two" or "Three"?  If so, the expression !/One|Two|Three/.test(myVar) is not correct.  The value "Ones" is not "One" but it *is* matched by /One/.  You want to use ^ and $.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming you mean "val does not equal One or Two or Three" then De Morgan's Theorem applies:

```
if ((val != "One") && (val != "Two") && (val != "Three")) {
  // Do something...
}
```

Comment: Equivalently, `!(var == "One" || var == "Two" || var == "Three")`.

Answer (score 0):

For a shorter way to do it, try this format (copied from http://snook.ca/archives/javascript/testing_for_a_v):

```
if(name in {'bobby':'', 'sue':'','smith':''}) { ... }
```

or

```
function oc(a)
{
  var o = {};
  for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++)
  {
    o[a[i]]='';
  }
  return o;
}
if( name in oc(['bobby', 'sue','smith']) ) { ... }
```

Comment: the second two methods are good, the first is wrong as discussed on other answers (`||` should be `&&`).

Comment: Thanks cobbal, I'll fix my answer.

Comment: I tried this before but it was lacking because I need the opposite. not in.

Comment: No cobbal, not && it needs to be ||

Comment: not (a or b) is equivalent to (not a) and (not b) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws

Answer (score 0):

The method mentioned by Mike will work fine for just 3 values, but if you want to extend it to `n` values, your `if` blocks will rapidly get ugly. Firefox 1.5+ and IE 8 have an `Array.indexOf` method you can use like so:

```
if(["One","Two","Test"].indexOf(myVar)!=-1)
{
    //do stuff
}
```

To support this method on IE<=7, you could define a method called Array.hasElement() like so:

```
Array.prototype.hasElement = function hasElement(someElement)
{
    for(var i=0;i<this.length;i++)
    {
        if(this[i]==someElement) 
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

And then call it like so:

```
if(!["One","Two","Three"].hasElement(myVar))
{
    //do stuff
}
```

Note: only tested in Firefox, where this works perfectly.

Answer (score -1):

Alternate way using an array:

```
var selected = ['Silverware', 'Gold Coins', 'Silver Coins'];
if ( selected.indexOf( el.value ) != -1 ) {
   // do something if it *was* found in the array of strings.
}
```

Note: `indexOf isnt a native method, grab the snippet here for IE:`

- https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/Array/IndexOf

Answer (score -1):

In addition to expanding the expression into three clauses, I think you'd better name your variable something other than `var`. In JavaScript, `var` is a keyword. Most browsers aren't going to alert you to this error.

Comment: the variable isnt really var. it was an example only.

Comment: +1 for pointing out the issue with `var` identifier.  I don't know why this is down voted.